# How can I RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR and do an INSERT in the same trigger?

Tags: oracle, trigger, exception, raiserror, ddl-trigger

From what I see, having the `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` cancels the other operations that I would have in the trigger. I tried writing first the `INSERT` and then the `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` hoping that they get executed in the order in which they are read but it doesn't work like this...The error is thrown and the `INSERT` is canceled. How could I make both of the operations get executed (from the same trigger) ?
I also tried creating two triggers .. one of them doing the `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` part and the other doing the `INSERT` and establishing the order using `FOLLOWS` and `PRECEDES` but it didn't work.
The trigger should block the `DROP` DDL (that's what for I used the `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`) and it also should do an insert in a `LOG` type table (that's what for I used the `INSERT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log type operations are usually done via `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` procedures.

Don't have a logging package, get one from GitHub.

https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger